# Looping within a select statement in SQL to calculate based on parameter

Tags: sql, loops

I need to parameterize my query so that for each period (1-12) it yields the balance for the period and the sum of all the balances for each period up to the selected period (YTD). My table looks like this (Am fields are amounts for each period in that year)

```
COMPANY|ACCOUNT|SUB_ACCOUNT|FISCAL_YEAR|DB_AMOUNT_01|DB_AMOUNT_02|DB_AMOUNT_03|DB_AMOUNT_04|DB_AMOUNT_05|DB_AMOUNT_06|DB_AMOUNT_07|DB_AMOUNT_08|DB_AMOUNT_09|DB_AMOUNT_10|DB_AMOUNT_11|DB_AMOUNT_12|
1|10000|1001|2014|176511106.65|200917064.20|243331258.93|189877339.46|208405555.85|316912751.86|413405072.40|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00
1|10020|1001|2014|7162276.27|10429413.89|12552480.96|11144442.08|8627365.16|13453884.90|12607065.52|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00
1|10040|1001|2014|8942858.81|11088886.79|11827043.98|12549230.43|12052482.22|12511277.79|9963556.61|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00
```

What I need to do is display the data for each period when user selects the period but with all the previous months added up for the beginning balance. So if the user selects Period 3, it should look like

```
COMPANY|ACCOUNT|SUB_ACCOUNT|FISCAL_YEAR|DB_AMOUNT_03|YTD_AMOUNT
1|10000|1001|2014|243331258.93|176511106.65+200917064.20+243331258.93
```

But for Period 4 it would be

```
COMPANY|ACCOUNT|SUB_ACCOUNT|FISCAL_YEAR|DB_AMOUNT_04|YTD_AMOUNT
1|10000|1001|2014|189877339.46|176511106.65+200917064.20+243331258.93+189877339.46
```

And so on

But how can I make that addition in the YTD_AMOUNT field when the period is chosen by the user?
I could write 12 different statements and do a IF/THEN  for each period but I would rather work in some logic that can do what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like you are trying to `unpivot` your table.  The answer can vary depending on your RDBMS, but this is a generic solution which should work as well.

You first need to create a numbers/period table.  One option is using a subquery with `UNION ALL` to achieve this.  You can then use an aggregate with `CASE` to get your desired results.

Here is a condensed version using 6 periods (add additional statements for 12 periods):

```
select company, account, sub_account, fiscal_year, 
  max(
    case 
      when amt = 1 then db_amount_01
      when amt = 2 then db_amount_02
      when amt = 3 then db_amount_03
      when amt = 4 then db_amount_04
      when amt = 5 then db_amount_05
      when amt = 6 then db_amount_06
     end
    ) amt, 
  sum(
    case 
      when amt = 1 then db_amount_01
      when amt = 2 then db_amount_01+db_amount_02
      when amt = 3 then db_amount_01+db_amount_02+db_amount_03
      when amt = 4 then db_amount_01+db_amount_02+db_amount_03+db_amount_04
      when amt = 5 then db_amount_01+db_amount_02+db_amount_03+db_amount_04+db_amount_05
      when amt = 6 then db_amount_01+db_amount_02+db_amount_03+db_amount_04+db_amount_05+db_amount_06
     end
    ) overallamt
from YourTable t , 
  (select 1 amt union all select 2 union all select 3 union all 
   select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) t2
group by company, account, sub_account, fiscal_year, amt
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66ea26/2)

Answer (score 1):

For a very large GL table where cross joining to a 12 period calendar table may be prohibitive performance-wise, an alternative solution is something like this:

```
declare @Period INT
set @Period = 4

select company, account, sub_account, fiscal_year, 
case @Period
when 1 then db_amount_01
when 2 then db_amount_02
when 3 then db_amount_03
when 4 then db_amount_04
....
end amt,
case @Period
when 1 then db_amount_01
when 2 then db_amount_01 + db_amount_02
when 3 then db_amount_01 + db_amount_02 + db_amount_03
when 4 then db_amount_01 + db_amount_02 + db_amount_03 + db_amount_04
....
end balance
from YourTable t
```

These tables often have a period opening balance column as well - you'll have to include that if necessary.

The difference between this and @sgeddes answer is this returns one row per account/year (i.e. just period 4), whereas @sgeddes returns multiple rows up to the specfied period (i.e. period 1-4)

It's not 100% clear from your question which one you want. Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you could make use of dynamic sql. I wrote the following targeting Sql Server. `@periodNum` is the parameter for the period number you're looking for; in this example I'm requesting the first 6 periods.

```
DECLARE @periodNum INT;
SET @periodNum = 6;

DECLARE @firstPeriodColNum INT;
DECLARE @periodCol NVARCHAR(50), @columnNm NVARCHAR(50), @prevColumnNm NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @queryTxt NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Columns TABLE (column_name NVARCHAR(50));

--Retrieve ordinal position for first period column
SELECT @firstPeriodColNum = ORDINAL_POSITION
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'DB_AMOUNT_01';

--Retrieve column name for period of interest
SELECT @periodCol = COLUMN_NAME
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' --just table name, no schema
                        AND ORDINAL_POSITION = (@periodNum + @firstPeriodColNum - 1);

--Retrieve column names for all periods up to and including the period of interest
INSERT INTO @Columns
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
    AND ORDINAL_POSITION >= @firstPeriodColNum 
       AND ORDINAL_POSITION < (@periodNum + @firstPeriodColNum);

--declare cursor over table variable of period-column names 
--run through cursor and dynamically add the column names to the query string @queryTxt
DECLARE COL_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM @Columns;
OPEN COL_CURSOR;

FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR INTO @columnNm;
SET @queryTxt = 'SELECT COMPANY, ACCOUNT, SUB_ACCOUNT, FISCAL_YEAR, ' 
                + @periodCol + ', (' + @columnNm;
SET @prevColumnNm = @columnNm;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
   FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR INTO @columnNm;
   IF @prevColumnNm <> @columnNm
   BEGIN
      SET @queryTxt = @queryTxt + ' + ' + @columnNm;
      SET @prevColumnNm = @columnNm;
   END
   ELSE CONTINUE
END
CLOSE COL_CURSOR;
DEALLOCATE COL_CURSOR;

SET @queryTxt = @queryTxt + ') AS YTD FROM YourTableName';

EXEC (@queryTxt); --Executes the query
```

Answer (score 0):

So I used a lot of your input (THANK YOU!!) and did it this way in the end:

```
  SELECT  distinct 
    d.ACCOUNT_DESC,
    a.COMPANY, 
    a.ACCOUNT, 
    a.SUB_ACCOUNT, 
    a.FISCAL_YEAR,
    CASE @period
    WHEN 1 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01
    WHEN 2 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02
    WHEN 3 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03
    WHEN 4 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04
    WHEN 5 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05
    WHEN 6 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_06+a.CR_AMOUNT_06
    WHEN 7 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_07+a.CR_AMOUNT_07
    WHEN 8 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_08+a.CR_AMOUNT_08
    WHEN 9 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_09+a.CR_AMOUNT_09
    WHEN 10 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_10+a.CR_AMOUNT_10
    WHEN 11 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_11+a.CR_AMOUNT_11
    WHEN 12 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_12+a.CR_AMOUNT_12
    WHEN 13 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_13+a.CR_AMOUNT_13

    END CHANGE ,
    CASE @period
    WHEN 2 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01 
    WHEN 3 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02
    WHEN 4 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03
    WHEN 5 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04
    WHEN 6 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04+a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05
    WHEN 7 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04+a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05+a.DB_AMOUNT_06+a.CR_AMOUNT_06
    WHEN 8 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04+a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05+a.DB_AMOUNT_06+a.CR_AMOUNT_06+a.DB_AMOUNT_07+a.CR_AMOUNT_07
    WHEN 9 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04+a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05+a.DB_AMOUNT_06+a.CR_AMOUNT_06+a.DB_AMOUNT_07+a.CR_AMOUNT_07+a.DB_AMOUNT_08+a.CR_AMOUNT_08
    WHEN 10 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04+a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05+a.DB_AMOUNT_06+a.CR_AMOUNT_06+a.DB_AMOUNT_07+a.CR_AMOUNT_07+a.DB_AMOUNT_08+a.CR_AMOUNT_08+a.DB_AMOUNT_09+a.CR_AMOUNT_09
    WHEN 11 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04+a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05+a.DB_AMOUNT_06+a.CR_AMOUNT_06+a.DB_AMOUNT_07+a.CR_AMOUNT_07+a.DB_AMOUNT_08+a.CR_AMOUNT_08+a.DB_AMOUNT_09+a.CR_AMOUNT_09+a.DB_AMOUNT_10+a.CR_AMOUNT_10
    WHEN 12 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04+a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05+a.DB_AMOUNT_06+a.CR_AMOUNT_06+a.DB_AMOUNT_07+a.CR_AMOUNT_07+a.DB_AMOUNT_08+a.CR_AMOUNT_08+a.DB_AMOUNT_09+a.CR_AMOUNT_09+a.DB_AMOUNT_10+a.CR_AMOUNT_10+a.DB_AMOUNT_11+a.CR_AMOUNT_11
    WHEN 13 THEN a.DB_AMOUNT_01+a.CR_AMOUNT_01+a.DB_AMOUNT_02+a.CR_AMOUNT_02+a.DB_AMOUNT_03+a.CR_AMOUNT_03+a.DB_AMOUNT_04+a.CR_AMOUNT_04+a.DB_AMOUNT_05+a.CR_AMOUNT_05+a.DB_AMOUNT_06+a.CR_AMOUNT_06+a.DB_AMOUNT_07+a.CR_AMOUNT_07+a.DB_AMOUNT_08+a.CR_AMOUNT_08+a.DB_AMOUNT_09+a.CR_AMOUNT_09+a.DB_AMOUNT_10+a.CR_AMOUNT_10+a.DB_AMOUNT_11+a.CR_AMOUNT_11+a.DB_AMOUNT_12+a.CR_AMOUNT_12
    END +a.DB_BEG_BAL + a.CR_BEG_BAL LAST_MONTH,
    a.DB_BEG_BAL + a.CR_BEG_BAL AS BEGINBAL,

    CASE @period
    WHEN 1 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01 
    WHEN 2 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02
    WHEN 3 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03
    WHEN 4 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04
    WHEN 5 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05
    WHEN 6 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05+z.DB_AMOUNT_06+z.CR_AMOUNT_06
    WHEN 7 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05+z.DB_AMOUNT_06+z.CR_AMOUNT_06+z.DB_AMOUNT_07+z.CR_AMOUNT_07
    WHEN 8 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05+z.DB_AMOUNT_06+z.CR_AMOUNT_06+z.DB_AMOUNT_07+z.CR_AMOUNT_07+z.DB_AMOUNT_08+z.CR_AMOUNT_08
    WHEN 9 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05+z.DB_AMOUNT_06+z.CR_AMOUNT_06+z.DB_AMOUNT_07+z.CR_AMOUNT_07+z.DB_AMOUNT_08+z.CR_AMOUNT_08+z.DB_AMOUNT_09+z.CR_AMOUNT_09
    WHEN 10 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05+z.DB_AMOUNT_06+z.CR_AMOUNT_06+z.DB_AMOUNT_07+z.CR_AMOUNT_07+z.DB_AMOUNT_08+z.CR_AMOUNT_08+z.DB_AMOUNT_09+z.CR_AMOUNT_09+z.DB_AMOUNT_10+z.CR_AMOUNT_10
    WHEN 11 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05+z.DB_AMOUNT_06+z.CR_AMOUNT_06+z.DB_AMOUNT_07+z.CR_AMOUNT_07+z.DB_AMOUNT_08+z.CR_AMOUNT_08+z.DB_AMOUNT_09+z.CR_AMOUNT_09+z.DB_AMOUNT_10+z.CR_AMOUNT_10+z.DB_AMOUNT_11+z.CR_AMOUNT_11
    WHEN 12 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05+z.DB_AMOUNT_06+z.CR_AMOUNT_06+z.DB_AMOUNT_07+z.CR_AMOUNT_07+z.DB_AMOUNT_08+z.CR_AMOUNT_08+z.DB_AMOUNT_09+z.CR_AMOUNT_09+z.DB_AMOUNT_10+z.CR_AMOUNT_10+z.DB_AMOUNT_11+z.CR_AMOUNT_11+z.DB_AMOUNT_12+z.CR_AMOUNT_12
    WHEN 13 THEN z.DB_AMOUNT_01+z.CR_AMOUNT_01+z.DB_AMOUNT_02+z.CR_AMOUNT_02+z.DB_AMOUNT_03+z.CR_AMOUNT_03+z.DB_AMOUNT_04+z.CR_AMOUNT_04+z.DB_AMOUNT_05+z.CR_AMOUNT_05+z.DB_AMOUNT_06+z.CR_AMOUNT_06+z.DB_AMOUNT_07+z.CR_AMOUNT_07+z.DB_AMOUNT_08+z.CR_AMOUNT_08+z.DB_AMOUNT_09+z.CR_AMOUNT_09+z.DB_AMOUNT_10+z.CR_AMOUNT_10+z.DB_AMOUNT_11+z.CR_AMOUNT_11+z.DB_AMOUNT_12+z.CR_AMOUNT_12+z.DB_AMOUNT_13+z.CR_AMOUNT_13
    END PYP
    from GLCONSOL a , GLCONSOL z, GLCHARTDTL d, GLMASTER m
    where ...
```